# Lazy load leaving huge gaps under image - CSS height issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, lazy-loading

I have a wordpress blog and have installed a lazy load plugin called BJ Lazy load. I am using the AVADA theme also.

When I scroll down the page, past the page fold there seems to be a large gap left under the image on all the post grid blog items.

I have found the fix/hack, where i apply a forced height of: -

```
.fusion-blog-layout-grid .fusion-post-wrapper .fusion-image-wrapper img {
    height: 230px; !important;
}
```

That works fine, but obviously when I shrink the page down, or view it on different devices the images get stretched.

Is there a better alternative to do here than force a height then have to do it for a bunch of other media queries?

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify the height for any images. Please try with below code.

```
.fusion-blog-layout-grid .fusion-post-wrapper .fusion-image-wrapper img
{
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Otherwise try with media query and define the height.

```
@media all and (max-width:1199px){

.fusion-blog-layout-grid .fusion-post-wrapper .fusion-image-wrapper img
    {
        height:;
    }

}

@media all and (max-width:991px){

.fusion-blog-layout-grid .fusion-post-wrapper .fusion-image-wrapper img
    {
        height:;
    }

}

@media all and (max-width:768px){

.fusion-blog-layout-grid .fusion-post-wrapper .fusion-image-wrapper img
    {
        height:;
    }

}

@media all and (max-width:480px){

.fusion-blog-layout-grid .fusion-post-wrapper .fusion-image-wrapper img
    {
        height:;
    }

}

@media all and (max-width:380px){

.fusion-blog-layout-grid .fusion-post-wrapper .fusion-image-wrapper img
    {
        height:;
    }

}

@media all and (max-width:320px){

.fusion-blog-layout-grid .fusion-post-wrapper .fusion-image-wrapper img
    {
        height:;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, the code already has your suggestion, it just seems that the lazy load plugin doesn't play nice with the theme. Although i have tried numerous other plugins and its the same. If i force a set height its ok, but there so many media queries I would have to do, just seems very hacky and not good

Comment: Can I see your div structure?. share your link, I will try?